# Disable same origin policy on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, same-origin-policy

Is there a way to disable the same origin policy on Android Chrome, I have searched the other posts and did not find any answers about android version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no way to disable the same origin policy because it's fundamental to the security of the web. There are some ways around it though, like [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), which should work in Chrome for Android.